# Retrieving value of EditTexts in AlertDialog builder using Layout

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Using the following code snippets, I'm trying to get the text value which has been typed in to the `EditText`s.

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View loginView = factory.inflate(R.layout.login, null);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Dialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewOrder.this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("Log In")
            .setView(loginView)
            .setPositiveButton("Log In", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    mSpinner = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Authenticating User...");
                    new LoginTask().execute();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                }
            })
            .create();
        d.show();
    }
});
```

My **login.xml** is pretty standard and straight forward:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:text="Email Address"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/password_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:text="Password"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:password="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When someone clicks the `PositiveButton`, how do I get the value of the `EditText` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.setPositiveButton("Log In", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        mSpinner =  ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Authenticating     User...");

        /* == Get EditText Values Example == */
        EditText edtext_username=  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        EditText edtext_password=  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        String ValueofUsername = edtext_username.getText().toString(); 
        String ValueofPassword = edtext_password.getText().toString();
        /* ========== End Example ========== */

        new LoginTask().execute();
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't think we can directly call `findViewById` like that in `OnClickListener` anonymous class. You have to use the already reference view `loginView `. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can directly call `findViewById()` like that in the anonymous class as the accepted answer suggests. For me it gives -

```
The method findViewById() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}
```

You have to call on the `View loginView` that you already have referenced to. Also it is important `loginView` be declared as final to reference it in anonymous class `OnClickListener`.

```
final View loginView = factory.inflate(R.layout.login, null);
// loginView should be declared final
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Dialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewOrder.this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("Log In")
            .setView(loginView)
            .setPositiveButton("Log In", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                   mSpinner = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Authenticating User...");
                   EditText usernameText=  (EditText) loginView.findViewById(R.id.username);
                   EditText passwordText=  (EditText) loginView.findViewById(R.id.password);
                   new LoginTask().execute();
                }
            })
            //more code
```

Comment: This is more acceptable if you are not using custom class for a dialog box and creating dialogbox on the go