# Dialog not pulling info from EditText box

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-edittext

Hello I am trying to write a small app and when the day is Sunday on the system it is supposed to pull up a dialog box which it is doing just fine.  However when I put info in the boxes in the dialog and click submit it is still showing the second dialog for the emptyBox I have set up.

So to recap all items of the dialog box are working except the system is still seeing the EditText boxes as empty but there is a value in there.  The value will only ever be numbers.

```
final Dialog sundayDialog = new Dialog(this);

    sundayDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sunday_dialog);
    Button sundaySubmitBtn = (Button) sundayDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.sundayDialogSubmitBtn);
    Button sundayCancelBtn = (Button) sundayDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.sundayDialogCancelBtn);

    sundaySubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Submit Button
            setContentView(R.layout.sunday_dialog);
            final EditText etAmountBought = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountBoughtET);
            final EditText etCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pricePaidET);
            String amountBought = etAmountBought.getText().toString();
            String cost = etCost.getText().toString();
            if (amountBought.isEmpty() || cost.isEmpty()) {

                //sundayDialog.dismiss();
                emptyETDialogCall();
            } else {
                try {

                    mAmountBought = Integer.parseInt(amountBought);
                    mPricePaid = Integer.parseInt(cost);

                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error in sunday dialog in try/catch");
                }
            }
            if (mPricePaid >= 250) {
                costTooHighDialogCall();
                mPricePaid = 0;
            }

            // textBlockDisplay(); // Update the text block with input.
        }

    });

    sundayCancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Cancel Button
            sundayDialog.dismiss();
            sundayCancelDialog();


        }
    });

    sundayDialog.show();
}
```

this is the only this that shows in logcat:

```
 08-04 11:42:44.780: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1209): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Take the findviewbyid of edit text to outside of onclick before the setonclicklistener

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295200/retrieving-value-of-edittexts-in-alertdialog-builder-using-layout

Comment: I tried both of those options and now it is trowing a nulpointer exception.  I commented out `setContentView(R.layout.sunday_dialog);` and now it throws a null pointer exception at line 161 which is the line that states `String amountBought = etAmountBought.getText().toString();` The next line is similar `String cost = etCost.getText().toString();`  Even after looking over the other question it brought no help.  Pretty much what I am getting from this issues is that the data is not being pulled from the EditText boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the reason, but each time, you're resetting the contentview. This should only be called once in onCreate, otherwise just remove the elements and use an inflater to add new ones. I think every time it resets the contentview, it will reset the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think, i got your problem .

**sundayDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sunday_dialog);
this is View you are setting for your custom Dialog. this is fine.**

> And after sunday click button again you are resetting your Layout
>   which again creates all views and you are getting everything reset.

final Dialog sundayDialog = new Dialog(this);

```
sundayDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sunday_dialog);
Button sundaySubmitBtn = (Button) sundayDialog
        .findViewById(R.id.sundayDialogSubmitBtn);
Button sundayCancelBtn = (Button) sundayDialog
        .findViewById(R.id.sundayDialogCancelBtn);

sundaySubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Submit Button
```

// Here i have removed setContent View....

```
        final EditText etAmountBought = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountBoughtET);
        final EditText etCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pricePaidET);
        String amountBought = etAmountBought.getText().toString();
        String cost = etCost.getText().toString();
        if (amountBought.isEmpty() || cost.isEmpty()) {

            //sundayDialog.dismiss();
            emptyETDialogCall();
        } else {
            try {

                mAmountBought = Integer.parseInt(amountBought);
                mPricePaid = Integer.parseInt(cost);

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in sunday dialog in try/catch");
            }
        }
        if (mPricePaid >= 250) {
            costTooHighDialogCall();
            mPricePaid = 0;
        }

        // textBlockDisplay(); // Update the text block with input.
    }

});

sundayCancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Cancel Button
        sundayDialog.dismiss();
        sundayCancelDialog();


    }
});

sundayDialog.show();
```

}

Comment: I have commented out `setContentView(R.layout.sunday_dialog);` and now it throws a null pointer exception at line 161 which is the line that states `String amountBought = etAmountBought.getText().toString();`
The next line is similar `String cost = etCost.getText().toString();`